# Joining tables with data from multiple categories

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a data of items in a table called items_data.

For each row, I have 3 columns that contain category labels (cat1, cat2, cat3). Some belong to three categories, while some contain only 1, of which cat2 and cat3 will have an empty cell.

The category labels are IDs which appear in another table called cat_label that contain two columns, one with the ID and one with the name of the catagory.

I want to join these two tables to form a new table such that if the item belongs to two catagories, there will be two rows created, and the output will be two columns, one with the item and ones with its category.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`

```
select a.item, b.name
from items_data a
join cat_label b on a.cat1 = b.id
union all 
select a.item, b.name
from items_data a
join cat_label b on a.cat2 = b.id
union all
select a.item, b.name
from items_data a
join cat_label b on a.cat3 = b.id
```

Comment: I think, in this case, 'union' and 'union all' will give same result set.

Comment: @VinitPrajapati, in that case `UNION ALL` is faster because it skips the dedupe part

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.cat1, c.cat_label from items_data i inner join cat_label c on i.cat1 = c.id
union
select i.cat2, c.cat_label from items_data i inner join cat_label c on i.cat2 = c.id
union
select i.cat3, c.cat_label from items_data i inner join cat_label c on i.cat3 = c.id
```